# clamav installation with pcre in Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk, clamav, pcre

When we install ClamAV in our Amazon Linux ElasticBeanstalk instance with `yum install clamav` it gets installed without PCRE support, although the libraries are present in the instance.

```
LibClamAV Warning: cli_loadldb: logical signature for Win.Trojan.ssid18332-1 
uses PCREs but support is disabled, skipping
LibClamAV Warning: cli_loadldb: logical signature for Win.Ransomware.Locky-4 
uses PCREs but support is disabled, skipping
LibClamAV Warning: cli_loadldb: logical signature for Html.Exploit.CVE_2016_0184-1 
uses PCREs but support is disabled, skipping
```

However PCRE is installed in the machine:

```
# yum install pcre
...
Package pcre-8.21-7.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Scanning is also very slow.

How can I force ClamAV to use/recognize the installed PCRE libraries in my Elastic Beanstalk machine?

Thanks!